# Translating a Word Problem into an Algebraic Equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

Find two consecutive odd integers such that three times the smaller one exceeds two times the larger one by $7$.

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: Unfortunately nothing :(

Comment: by my Guess the answer is 11,13

but i don't how i make it in formulas

Comment: no body can solve it?!

Comment: I answered a [similar quesiton](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/845462/translating-text-to-functions/845478) a little while ago, you might try to read that answer to get some more practice for turning words into algebraic expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x$ be the least of two consecutive odd numbers. So the greater of the two consecutive odd numbers must be $x+2$.

Now, we want [three times the smaller odd number] to *exceed* [twice the larger odd number] by $7$. So the difference between $3x$ and $2(x+1)$ should equal seven.

$$3x -2(x+2) = 7 \quad\iff \quad x = 11$$

So we have the least of the odd numbers. What is the next consecutive odd number after $x$?

Comment: thenk you for explien :)

Comment: by mean = here?

Answer (score 0):

"Find two consecutive odd integers..."

OK, that's $2k+1, \space2k+3$, where $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

"...such that three times the smaller one..."

$$3(2k+1)$$

"...exceeds two times the larger one..."

$$ 2(2k+3)$$

..."by 7."

$$3(2k+1)=2(2k+3)+7$$

Solve for $k=5$, and then plug that into $2k+1$ and $2k+3$ to get $11$ and $13$, respectively.

Comment: why you put 2k ??

Comment: i don't get it ,

Comment: What is an even number?

Comment: I know what the Question mean, but what have to do with that?

Comment: If you answer me, I can explain to you how I got 2k+1.

Comment: my english is too weak, i can't answer, but i know waht even number mean in arabic :)

Comment: it's any numer can divied over 2 , maybe

Comment: so why you put 2k now?

Comment: If k is an integer (which I claimed it to be), then 2k is an even number. Thus, 2k+1 is an odd number. Since we don't know what the odd numbers we want are, we begin with 2k+1, where k can be anything.

Comment: now i get it, like i thougt

Comment: thenk you for your explien :)

Comment: You're welcome. Give my post an upvote if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Three times the smaller one exceeds two times the larger one by 7.

$\text{Three times the smaller one} = \text{(two times the larger one)} + 7$.

$3\times\text{the smaller one} = 2\times\text{(the larger one)} + 7$.

$3\times\text{the smaller one} = 2\times(\text{the smaller one}+2) + 7$.

$3x = 2(x+2) + 7$

$\dots$

Comment: I would also like to add that $x=2t+1$. Sorry about that everyone.